# Android Broadcastreceiver with listener

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, listener, classcastexception

I have a Broadcastreceiver for monitoring network state. When it changes I want to send a custom Exception to my BaseActivity in order that can be showed in any Activity.

To send the exception I have a listener, which is implemented on my BaseActivity.

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ConnectionStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private ConnectionStateListener connectionStateListener;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.connectionStateListener = (ConnectionStateListener) context;

        if (this.connectionStateListener != null) {
            this.connectionStateListener.showConnectionStateLostException(new NetworkConnectionException());
        }
        ......
```

Listener:

```
public interface ConnectionStateListener {
    void showConnectionStateLostException(Exception exception);
}
```

BaseActivity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ConnectionStateListener, BatteryChangeListener {

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    this.batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    //Receiver called when battery level changes
    this.systemBatteryLevelReceiver = new BatteryChangeReceiver();

    registerReceiver(systemBatteryLevelReceiver, ifilter);

}

...
@Override
public void showConnectionStateLostException(Exception exception) {
    showSystemStateMessage(ExceptionMessageUtils.createSystemExceptionMessage(this, exception));
}

@Override
public void showChangeBatteryException(Exception exception) {
    showSystemStateMessage(ExceptionMessageUtils.createSystemExceptionMessage(this, exception));
}
...
```

Manifest:

```
...
<receiver android:name=".data.broadcastreceivers.ConnectionStateReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The problem is when it trys to do the cast on the receiver:

```
this.connectionStateListener = (ConnectionStateListener) context;
```

It gives me the following error:

```
01-14 11:45:38.347    8766-8766/com.massfactory.mobile.android.stlparatransit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.massfactory.mobile.android.stlparatransit, PID: 8766
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.massfactory.mobile.android.stlparatransit.data.broadcastreceivers.ConnectionStateReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to com.massfactory.mobile.android.stlparatransit.domain.broadcastlisteners.ConnectionStateListener at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2593) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to com.massfactory.mobile.android.stlparatransit.domain.broadcastlisteners.ConnectionStateListener
        at com.massfactory.mobile.android.stlparatransit.data.broadcastreceivers.ConnectionStateReceiver.onReceive(ConnectionStateReceiver.java:37)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2586)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I have another broadcast wich is monitoring battery state with the same "structure" and doesn't give any problem, the only diference is that the "battery broadcast" is declared dinamically (not in the manifest as this one).

Battery Listener:

```
public interface BatteryChangeListener {
   void showChangeBatteryException(Exception exception);
}
```

Any idea why is happening this and what I should do to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where you are registering for ConnectionStateReceiver?

Comment: In the manifest, sorry I had forgotten to put the manifest code.

Comment: Can you remove registering code from manifest and implement it in java file and check? That should work properly. have you tried that?

Comment: good luck with that :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to register the ConnectionStateReceiver into the Activity and remove it from manifest as EagleEye commented.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ConnectionStateListener, BatteryChangeListener {

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    this.batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    //Receiver called when battery level changes
    this.systemBatteryLevelReceiver = new BatteryChangeReceiver();

    registerReceiver(systemBatteryLevelReceiver, ifilter);


     //Check Network State
     this.iFilterConnectionState = new IntentFilter();             this.iFilterConnectionState.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);        
     this.systemConnectionStateReceiver = new ConnectionStateReceiver();        
     registerReceiver(this.systemConnectionStateReceiver, iFilterConnectionState);

}
```